# Pandas - Given a date column, find the closet previous date in another column group by ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['001','002','003','001','002','001'],
                   'chkin':['2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-20','2017-01-15','2017-03-06'],
                   'chkout':['2017-01-05','2017-01-10','2017-01-04','2017-01-27','2017-01-31','2017-03-10']})
df['chkin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['chkin'])
df['chkout'] = pd.to_datetime(df['chkout'])
```

I would like to produce a new column called 'previous_visit' by comparing a given date in a column (chkout) and previous dates in another column (chkin) for each ID.  The expected output should be the following.

```
 ID       chkin      chkout      previous_visit
001    2017-01-01   2017-01-05         NaT
002    2017-01-02   2017-01-10         NaT
003    2017-01-03   2017-01-04         NaT
001    2017-01-20   2017-01-27     2017-01-01
002    2017-01-15   2017-01-31     2017-01-02
001    2017-03-06   2017-03-10     2017-01-20
```

I think that using `df.groupby('ID').transform(some_custom_function, df)` might solve this problem but I could not manage to get such a function.  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` to get the previous value i.e

```
df['prev'] = df.groupby('ID')['chkin'].shift()
```

Output :

```
   ID      chkin     chkout       prev
0  001 2017-01-01 2017-01-05        NaT
1  002 2017-01-02 2017-01-10        NaT
2  003 2017-01-03 2017-01-04        NaT
3  001 2017-01-20 2017-01-27 2017-01-01
4  002 2017-01-15 2017-01-31 2017-01-02
5  001 2017-03-06 2017-03-10 2017-01-20
```